# Move a simple Window left or right in C

Tags: c, graphics, gtk, shortcut

I have a simple window in C and I'm trying to move it to the left and right by pressing ctrl+left or ctrl+right. I already have declared the shortcuts.

```
case GDK_KEY_Left: left(window); return TRUE;
case GDK_KEY_Right: right(window); return TRUE;
```

I wrote a couple dummy functions just to check if they work.

```
void left(void) {
    g_print("Left");
}

void right(void) {
    g_print("Right");

}
```

The messages are printed when running it from my terminal, but I have no idea how to move it to the desired positions.

How am i supposed to proceed?

Thanks in advance.
Christian.

Comment: I assume your container has a position. Change it when the keys are pressed. We have no idea what a container is or what you're doing other than the few lines of code you've shown.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm sorry if I wasn't that clear. I meant a simple blank window.

Comment: @ChristianPix C does not have windows or any concept of such, you will have to add more details to your question.

Comment: Also note that "moving a window" from the client itself isn't necessarily supported (for example in Wayland)

Comment: @Fredrik sorry, it's in gtk3 :)